# What is the best way to connect to the Ethereum Blockchain from a Deno application?

Tags: web3js

I have created a smart contract which I can interact with using regular TypeScript and Web3. Is there a way to interact with smart contracts using Deno?

Answer (score 3):

This module might be what you are looking for:
https://deno.land/x/web3